# How can i track the value of a variable with a breakpoint

Tags: xcode4.3

it may be obvious with the new Xcode Debugger, but, i couldn't see the actual value:

```
int i=0; //i put a breakpoint on this line
i=1;
i=2;
```

When the app stopped on the first line, i put the mouse cursor on the `i` and something should refer me the correct value, means `0`, but this was not the case. I also try to print the value on the console:

```
print i
```

But i got this:

```
(int) $1 = <unsufficient data for value (only 0 of 4 bytes available)>
```

Although i am sure po is not for primitives, i tried it too:

```
po i
```

Nothing from the above ways has worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

i just had the same problem. this fixed it for me:

go to "edit scheme", then "Run", then "Info", then "build Configuration" and **select "Debug"** instead of "Release".

@Apple: BTW it should be called "insufficient" :-)